# Failed kernel upgrade - depmod syntax error?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, data-corruption

I have encountered a problem trying to upgrade my kernel (`linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic`). I was getting this error:

```
Running depmod.
Failed to run depmod
```

I checked the permissions on depmod:

```
root@mycomputer:~# la -la /sbin | grep depmod
-r--r--r--  1 myuser   myuser      1119 gru 20 16:26 depmod
```

It was read-only and the owner and group was set to my non-root user. After changing the owner to root and giving him +x, I get this error:

```
Running depmod.
/sbin/depmod: 1: /sbin/depmod: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Failed to run depmod
```

Just trying to run depmod:

```
root@AP137:~# depmod
-su: /sbin/depmod: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I honestly don't know what have I done to break this but the depmod binary   is probably corrupted. Is there a way to recover from this?

Comment: Reinstalling kmod worked, thanks @Ravexina, you should upgrade your comment to an answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `depmod` command is a part of `kmod` package so I think reinstalling it will fix your issue.

First run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure kmod
```

to reconfigure this package without reinstalling it,
 if it didn't work then:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kmod
```